# How to store an id of data based on checked value or (all)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Say that I have an e-commerce that 100 kind of products. Now, I'm offering a voucher for the customer. The voucher can be used for some of the products or all products.

So, the table I have now is like this:

```
|      Voucher   |
------------------
| id             |
| voucher_number |
| created_at     |
| expired_date   |
| status         | (available, unavailable)

| Voucher_detail |
------------------
| id             |
| id_voucher     |
| product_id     |
```

So, the question is, if the voucher is set to be available for all products. There will be 100 records in voucher_detail because there are 100 products. Isn't it a waste, because the voucher will only be used for one products.

Or there are another database design that is better than this one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there is a better design for your situation. I mean, when designing the database, it should fit all the use-cases, and this way, you cover them all.

Of course, when having a voucher for all the products it needs 100 rows, but this perfectly suits the situation where you have the voucher for like 5 products, and it is a secure and sure way to know exactly each voucher for what products it can be used.

Was thinking, maybe you could have all the products for the voucher, in a column, separated by ',' and split them when reading (if you really care about size) but that just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't generate more than a small subset of the 2^100-1 possible combinations, correct?  Perhaps you have only a few, and they can be itemized as "all", "clothing", "automotive", etc.?  If so ponder working around that.

If you really need true/false for 100 things, consider the `SET` datatype.  Since it is restricted to 64 bits, you will need at least 2 `SET` columns.  Again, you may decide to 'group' the bits in some logical way.  At one bit per item, we are talking about around a dozen bytes for the entire 100 choices.

"all" would probably be represented as every bit being on.

With the `SET` approach, you would have string names for each of th 100 cases.  The `SET` would be any combination of them.  Please study the manual on `SET`; the manipulations are a bit strange.